# If this a typo in my book: Radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{n! z^n}{n^n} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Im trying to find the radius of convergence of $$\sum \frac{n! z^n}{n^n} $$

Let $a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}$ so I know the radius of convergence $R$ is the limit of  $\lvert a_n/a_{n+1}\rvert$ which I get to be $1$. However, book says $R$ should be $e$.

Comment: I get the limit of $| \frac{n+1}{n}|^{n} = | (1 + \frac{1}{n}) |^{n},$ which equals $e.$

Comment: The limit is $e$ (see my answer), so this is no typo. Just insert a large number (lets say $10^5$) and see the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{n!}{n^n}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^n} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to \cdots \text{ as }n\to \infty 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$